# how to use "filerenameupload" filter in zend framework2?

Tags: forms, file-upload, filter, zend-framework2

i add file element in form class with:

```
        $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\File',
        'name' => 'logo_file',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Select your logo image file:',
        ),
    ));
```

then add filter in model for filtering form data. i use "filerenameupload" filter to upload selected file :

```
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name'     => 'logo_file',
            'required' => false,
            'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'filerenameupload',
                    'options'=>array(
                        //'target'    => "./data/logo.png",
                        'randomize' => true,
                    )
                ),
            ),
        )));
```

and in controller i call setInputFilter, setData and isValid normally. other elements go filter good, but "logo_file" does not be saved in "./data/logo.png".
in fact "filter" function in "Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload" class does not be executed.

i use this link :
[zf2 File Uploding Toturial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html#file-post-redirect-get-plugin)

Someone's trying to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the full name for the Filter?

```
array(
    'name' => 'Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload'
)
```

You also need to make sure you add both the files array and the POST data to the form when validating, example:

```
$postArr = $request->getPost()->toArray();
$fileArr = $this->params()->fromFiles('logo_file');
$formData = array_merge(
     $postArr, // $_POST
     array('logo_file' => $fileArr['name']) // $_FILE...
);
$importForm->setData($formData);
```

Comment: it helped me. but in array_merge, i use:
array('logo_file'=>$fileArr.
thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Form.php:

```
public function addElements(){
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'image',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'file',
        ),
        'options' => array(
        ),
    ));
```

FormValidator.php

```
public function getInputFilter()
{
    if (!$this->inputFilter) {

        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
        $factory = new InputFactory();

        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    "name" => "image",
                    "required" => true,
                    "filters" => array(
                        array("name" => "StripTags"),
                        array("name" => "StringTrim"),
                        array(
                            "name" => "Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload",
                            "options" => array(
                                "target" => '/home/limonazzo/UPLOADDIR<----------',
                                "randomize" => true,
                                "use_upload_name" => true,
                                "use_upload_extension" => true
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    "validators" => array(
                        array(
                            "name" => "Zend\Validator\File\IsImage",
                            "break_chain_on_failure" => true,
                            "options" => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                        array(
                            "name" => "Zend\Validator\File\Extension",
                            "break_chain_on_failure" => true,
                            "options" => array(
                                "extension" => "jpg,jpeg,png",
                            ),
                        ),
                        array(
                            "name" => "Zend\Validator\File\Size",
                            "break_chain_on_failure" => true,
                            "options" => array(
                                "min" => "1kB",
                                "max" => "1024kB",
                            ),
                        ),
                        array(
                            "name" => "Zend\Validator\File\ImageSize",
                            "break_chain_on_failure" => true,
                            "options" => array(
                                "minWidth" => 10,
                                "minHeight" => 10,
                                "maxWidth" => 250,
                                "maxHeight" => 350,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
        )));
```

In controlle.php

```
$form = new Form();
$formValidator = new FormValidator();
$form->setInputFilter($formValidator->getInputFilter(''));
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $data = $form->getData(\Zend\Form\FormInterface::VALUES_AS_ARRAY);
    $imgName = $data["image"]["tmp_name"];
```